# How to use composition with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have something like this:

```
dog = function () {
  this.age;
  this.name;
  this.dog1 = new dog.shepherd();
}

dog.prototype = {
  bark : function () {
    alert( (this.getName()) + " is barking." );
  },

  [3]**getName** : function () {
    return this.name;
  }
}

dog.shepherd = function () {
  this.something;
}

dog.shepherd.prototype = function () {
  guard : function () {
        alert( ([2]**parent.getName()**) + " is barking." );
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  var n = new dog();
  [1]**n.guard()**;
}
```

How can I use a function which is prototyped to the dog from dog.speherd prototype?

In other words, when [1] is executed, then [2] is written in pseudo-code, to call [3].

I know this code shouldn't work; it's just to help me explain what I want.

Comment: It's not really clear what it is that you want/expect to happen.  What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Christoph: Are you aware that `dog.shepherd = function () { this.something; }` has no impact on inheritance? You're just referencing one function on a property of another function.

Comment: Are you just trying to make a Shepherd subclass for dog or are you trying to have dogs have the shepherd methods?

Comment: I've been thinking about it. I wanted to reference one function to another, but I should use inheritance here as I think more deeply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title says you want to use composition, but your question body implies inheritance.  Here's how you would do this with composition, which is probably the better option.  A shepherd "is not a" dog after all (nor vice versa) so inheritance probably isn't right here.

Also, you usually don't want to set the entire prototype of a function like you're doing; just add the functions you want.  And constructor functions by convention start with a capital letter.

```
function Shepherd(mydog) { 
    this.dog = mydog;
}
Shepherd.prototype.guard = function () {
    alert( this.dog.getName() + " is barking." );
}

function Dog(age, name) {
  this.age = age;
  this.name = name;
}

Dog.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.name;
}

Dog.prototype.bark = function () {
    alert(this.getName() + " is barking." );
}

window.onload = function () {
  var someDog = new Dog(4, "Ubu");
  var someShepherd = new Shepherd(someDog);      
  someShepherd.guard();
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lcustodio/8E6tZ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need such code, but you can try this:

```
dog = function () {
  this.age;
  this.name;
  this.dog1 = new dog.shepherd(this);

  var d = this.dog1;
  for (var i in dog.shepherd.prototype) {
    this[i] = function(){
       return this.dog1[i].apply(d, arguments);
    }
  }
}

dog.prototype = {
  bark : function () {
    alert( (this.getName()) + " is barking." );
  },

  getName : function () {
    return this.name;
  }
}

dog.shepherd = function (parent) {
  this.parent = parent;
  this.something;
}

dog.shepherd.prototype = {
  guard : function () {
        alert( (this.parent.getName()) + " is barking." );
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  var n = new dog();
  n.guard();
}
```